# 'Normal' is excplicitly unavailable in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm taking a course on Udacity, the program has been taught with an older version of Xcode.

Still trying to figure out the differences with the new version of Xcode.  Any help is appreciated.

Thank you all!

```
button.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 250, width: 60, height: 60)
button.setTitle ("Click", for: .Normal)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: Normal)
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

The following error messages are showing up:

> `Normal` is explicitly marked unavailable here
>
> use of unresolved identifier `normal`

Comment: Taking a course using Swift 2 is going to be a serious challenge. Find a modern course using at least Swift 3.

Comment: Thank you.  It's a company sponsored course.  I have to make do.

Comment: Your company is setting you up for failure. Everything changed in Swift 3. Learning Swift 2 is a giant step backwards. Tell your company this needs to be stopped.

Comment: Ouch! And yet - the error says it. Change `Normal` to `normal`. You likely need **much** more on that line - first off a period in front of `normal` and getting rid of `Color`. Here's my "big picture" thought. Your employer.  They *definitely* do not understand the annual/historical nature of Swift. Swift 2 is **nothing** like Swift 4 (nor Swift 3 even). That's what @rmaddy is saying. Either *they* need to understand this or *you* need to either find another employer - yes, not exactly easy - of find a way to tell them how much they **are** setting you (or anyone) up for failure.

Answer (score 1):

After Swift 3, enums became **lowercased**. You are also missing a dot before the enum.

Also, `UIColor` colors are now **static variables** instead of functions with a return value.

```
button.setTitle("Click", for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 2, you are missing a dot.

```
button.setTitle ("Click", for: .Normal)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal) // <-- Added dot.
```

---

In Swift 4.0, there are API changes.

```
button.setTitle("Click", for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
```